# Newline not remove from string in PHP

Tags: php, json, zend-form

I have a Zend form, which description field is a `textarea` element.

I fill the description `textarea` with newline(ENTER) and post that form. At the time of saving data in DB I try to remove the newlines with no space because I have to store it in DB to Json. If I do not remove the newline then the json is not decoded properly.

So after lot of R&D I got to know that JSON do not support multi line string.

I have tried

```
<!-- language: php -->

$string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
$string = str_replace("\r", "", $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[ \t]+/',  ' ', $string);
```

If I check the above solution by taking in `temp` variable and it's working fine but not with Zend form post data.

Comment: Either use 1- nl2br function or  2- just explode your string with newline, it gives you array directly and you can easily encode it. No need to do any extra effort.

Comment: I have tried with nl2br but no result .All the  possible result i have tried

Comment: try explode. and check

Comment: try json_encode($string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried  below solution and it works fine

```
$val = array("\n","\r");
$string = str_replace($val, "", $string);
```